# How do I get Intel Processor Trace working with virtual addresses

Tags: windows, x86-64, intel

I'm trying to make a driver for Intel Processor Trace (Intel PT) to trace kernel code and learn more about my operating system, but I'm not sure how I can access this data when the output is purely physical addresses and I'm in protected mode. How can I work with Intel PT on windows 7 in protected mode? Or alternatively if that's not possible, is there any way I can get where a virtual address resides in physical address space?

EDIT: I may have a solution if I can find some predictable contiguous physical memory, I have a trick to write physical memory but I'm afraid of blindly overwriting data that's in use, so if there's any physical memory addresses that have 100% predictable data please let me know and I will test my theory and if it works write up a solution to this question.

Comment: Are you asking how to read the trace data or how to interpret it? To read it, of course you need to map the pages containing the trace data into the virtual address space in order to access it.

Comment: There is no specific x86 instruction to translate a virtual address to a physical address. Operating systems generally have functions to do it, but I don't know about Windows specifically. Applications cannot generally perform the translation because they don't have access to the page tables and other data structures that the OS maintains to support memory mapping.

Comment: @prl I don't need to know how to interpret it, I've read and generally understand how to do that. I'm looking for a way to give my application access to the physical addresses that contain the data.